# SAGE - Listing points on an elliptic curve

Tags: math, point, sage, elliptic-curve

I have a generated elliptic curve of a modulus. I want to list just a few points on it (doesn't matter what they are, I just need one or two) and I was hoping to do:

```
E.points()
```

However due to the size of the curve this generates the error:

```
OverflowError: range() result has too many items
```

I attempted to list the first four by calling it as such:

```
E.points()[:4]
```

However that generated the same error

Is there any way I can make it list just a few points? Maybe some Sage function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not include code to reproduce your situation, I take an example curve from the Sage documentation:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(101),[23,34])
```

## Generating random points

You can repeatedly use `random_element` or `random_point` to choose points at random:

```
sage: E.random_point()
(99 : 92 : 1)
sage: E.random_point()
(27 : 80 : 1)
```

This is probably the simplest way to obtain a few arbitrary points on the curve. `random_element` works in many places in Sage.

## Intersecting with lines

It has the defining polynomial

```
sage: p = E.defining_polynomial(); p
-x^3 + y^2*z - 23*x*z^2 - 34*z^3
```

which is homogeneous in `x,y,z`. One way to find *some* points on that curve is by intersecting it with straight lines. For example, you could intersect it with the line `y=0` and use `z=1` to choose representatives (thus omitting representatives at `z==0`) using

```
sage: p(y=0,z=1).univariate_polynomial().roots(multiplicities=False)
[77]
```

So at that point you know that `(77 : 0 : 1)` is a point on your curve. You can automate things, intersecting with different lines until you have reached the desired number of points:

```
sage: res = []
sage: y = 0
sage: while len(res) < 4:
....:     for x in p(y=y,z=1).univariate_polynomial().roots(multiplicities=False):
....:         res.append(E((x, y, 1)))
....:     y += 1
....:
sage: res[:4]
[(77 : 0 : 1), (68 : 1 : 1), (23 : 2 : 1), (91 : 4 : 1)]
```

## Adapting `points()`

You can have a look at how the `points()` method is implemented. Type `E.points??` and you will see that it uses an internal method called [`_points_via_group_structure`](http://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.py?h=f0f7b3a1b3b68688610cef5d131ae696f3034c7b#n116). Looking at the source of that (using `E._points_via_group_structure??` or the [link to the repo](http://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.py?h=f0f7b3a1b3b68688610cef5d131ae696f3034c7b#n116)), you can see how that is implemented, and probably adapt it to only yield a smaller result. In particular you can see what role that `range` plays here, and use a smaller range instead.